# Why is my promise not returning with angularjs 1.2.*

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

My promise seem to not be resolving when I try to pass it directly to my view, It works when I go through the .then method.

Example here http://jsbin.com/oworucAL/1/edit

Comment: By changing the AngularJS version, you'll see that the data comes in on Angular 1.0.x & 1.1.x, but not in 1.2.1.

Comment: Answer can be found in this SO thread:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472017/angularjs-promise-not-binding-to-template-in-1-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetData return a promise, and you must manage it.

```
app.controller('RepeatController', function ($scope, DataFactory) {
     DataFactory.getData().then( function(data){ 
     $scope.weeks = data; }, 
     function (){}); 
 })  ;
```

http://jsbin.com/iYApuFE/1/edit

Comment: This has been answered in the other SO thread, but I will mark your answer as correct anyway.