# What is the correct way of handling angular resource 1.2.x get queries?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I am currently working on implementing a REST API with Angular resource 1.2.x. I just came across several hints that with the 1.2.x release, angular-resource broke some existing patterns. My question is now, how to handle the following scenario with angular-resource 1.2.x correctly.

I do have a REST API that returns data (/offers/:id) and a angular service that abstracts those API by using angular-resource. Within this service I do have a get function that queries the API with the given id:

```
_offerResource.get({offerId: id})
```

The _offerResource itself is an instance of $resource.

In my controller, I do have a variable offer on the $scope to which the view is bound (e.g. $scope.offer.title, ...).

I tried to implement the call to the API with the following line of code:

```
_tempOffer = OfferAPI.get($routeParams.offerId)
```

But unfortunately the bindings are not working. Based on this SO entry ([Angularjs promise not binding to template in 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472017/angularjs-promise-not-binding-to-template-in-1-2)) the behavior of angular-resource has changed. But is the approach with using the $promise.then(...) statement the way to go? From an engineering point of view this looks quite ugly, as I need to take care of this in the controller, rather than the service returning me an object that I just can use.

This one works, but as stated above, it is not my favorite approach from a SW design point of view:

```
    _tempOffer = OfferAPI.get($routeParams.offerId)
    _tempOffer.$promise.then((response) ->
        $scope.offer = Offer.initializeFromJSON(response.offer)
    )
```

I convert the response of the API into another object btw, so I need to have the following transformation before I can bind the offer object to the $scope.offer variable:

```
$scope.offer = Offer.initializeFromJSON(response.offer)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This has been what I've been doing so far. It works pretty well despite being ugly/verbose. It also seems to be the current way to do things from what I can tell. The problem I'm currently having is sharing that response data across multiple controllers. I'll be watching the answers you get.