# Bower angular-route 1.x.x install issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

Due to [promise binding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472017/angularjs-promise-not-binding-to-template-in-1-2) in angular `1.2.x` I would like to use angular `1.x.x` but I am unable to install angular-route `1.x.x` On [bower-angular-route](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route) I can't find any version lower than `1.2.x` is there any work around?

Angular promise issue is demonstrated on this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ch4nd4n/YS5eu/). You would notice that resolved object binds fine to the template on angular version `1.1.1` but fails in angular version `1.2.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since angular version 1.2.x `ngroute` is separate inclusion. [AngularJS 1.2 $injector:modulerr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287482/angularjs-1-2-injectormodulerr) I had to remove explicit inclusion in app initialization. I had to remove `ngRoute` from module binding.