# Working with promises in Angular

Tags: node.js, angularjs, promise, bluebird

I am trying to adapt a NodeJs/AngularJs tutorial http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-tv-show-tracker-using-angularjs-nodejs-and-mongodb/ to using Postgres and the Sequelize ORM. The ORM has changed as it now uses Bluebird promises.

I'm hitting my database to return a number of TV shows and in return I get a list of shows and their episodes. This is the html before I used promises:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3" ng-repeat="show in shows | filter:query | orderBy:'rating':true">
    <a href="/shows/{{show.id}}"><img class="img-rounded" ng-src="{{show.poster}}" width="100%"></a>
    <div class="text-center">
        <a href="/shows/{{show.id}}">{{show.name}}</a>
        <p class="text-muted">Episodes: {{show.episodes.length}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I use the $resource service and a ng-repeat loop, however since I changed to promises I don't seem to be able to access the episodes, but in my console I see the $scope.shows is equal 
to:

```
[$promise: Object, $resolved: false]
0: Resource
$$hashKey: 57
Episodes: Array[68]
airs_day_of_week: "Sunday"
airs_time: "9:00 PM"
createdAt: "2014-10-14T10:29:27.287Z"
first_aired: "2008-01-20T00:00:00.000Z"
genre: Array[4]
id: 81189
name: "Breaking Bad"
network: "AMC"
overview: "Walter White, a struggling high school chemistry teacher, is diagnosed with advanced lung cancer. He turns to a life of crime, producing and selling methamphetamine accompanied by a former student, Jesse Pinkman, with the aim of securing his family's financial future before he dies."
poster: "posters/81189-22.jpg"
rating: "9.30"
rating_count: 645
status: "Ended"
updatedAt: "2014-10-14T10:29:27.287Z"
__proto__: Resource
$promise: Object
$resolved: true
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

How can I access the episodes.length now? show.name works but show.episodes.length returns undefined.

My resource invocation looks like this:

in the controller:

```
$scope.shows = Show.query();
```

in the services:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .factory('Show', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource('/api/shows/:id');
        }]);
```

Comment: It seems the shows is an `object` instead of `array`. How does your resource invocation look like.

Comment: Have amended my question accordingly.

Comment: It is an array, can you check in console what $scope.shows[0] prints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth to note that you can't freely put promises in your templates and expect Angular to resolve them since v 1.2:

Take a look at this SO:

[Angularjs promise not binding to template in 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472017/angularjs-promise-not-binding-to-template-in-1-2).

What you can do when you are getting your results from your service, is to put the results, not the promise, in scope:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SU5UMK7jNffXWnWiV1HE?p=preview

```
SomeService.getSomeData().then(function(res) {
  $scope.someData = res;
});
```

In your case, probably more like:

`ShowsService.getShows().then(function(shows) {
    $scope.shows = shows;
 });`

Edit: Of course, since you are using $resource, and not Restangular, you should convert my example to something that $resource would find acceptable:

```
Show.query('', function(shows){
     $scope.shows = shows;
});
```

Comment: I tried to do your suggestion, by amending Show.query(); `Show.query().then(function (shows) {$scope.shows = shows;})` see the edited question, it returns `TypeError: undefined is not a function.`

Comment: I think I did a stupid mistake in my Angular/HTML code, once I changed to `{{show.Episodes.length}}`, everything worked fine!! I did learn something in the meantime so thanks!