# angularjs to wait for response from server, similar to callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback

I am running into an issue where the client is not waiting for the server response.  I have a big query that runs on server and returns data.  But on client side, it is not waiting for the response from server before processing the data.
I tried angularjs .then function without success.
Service is "myService" as below.

```
this.getJsonData = function() {
    var searchData =  caller.get("/metadata/Search").then(function(result){
      return result.data;
    });
    return searchData;
  };
```

calling service

```
myService.getJsonData().then(
    function(data) {
     formatData(data);
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log("Error here" + err);
    });
```

Now formatData is called, while the response from server call in pending in getJsonData.

Can anyone please help me what could be done here to resolve the issue.

**********Edited**********
Tried this but didn't work either

```
this.getJsonData = function() {
    var deffered = $q.seDefer();
    caller.get("/metadata/Search").then(function(result){
      deffered.resolve(result.data);
    });
    return deffered.promises;
  };
```

Comment: Could this data be loaded upfront before loading DOM content?

Comment: i can only run this data fetch when user clicks on a button

Comment: And you are trying to do so via an ajax request? If so then you may want to add a loading modal to the page to show users that work is happening in the background, then just hide the modal when the data is available from the outgoing ajax request.

Comment: its not an UI screen blocker issue.  Even before the data is returned, formatData loop is getting executed resulting in error.  It has to do something with $q, defer and resolve functions in promises.

Comment: Yes, promises would definitely be the route that you want to go. See this for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238928/angularjs-http-call-in-a-service-return-resolved-data-not-promises

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can use promises with long running calls: http://fiddle.jshell.net/82vLx76y/

By returning a promise from a function, we can defer the execution of another chained function and make use of the first functions return value. See Angular's $q service documentation for more info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: I tried to add timeout, but that just waited for sometime but didn't actually wait for the server response.

Comment: Don't use a timeout, it is only there to simulate a long running task. Execute your long running data function instead and resolve $q at the end of it.

Comment: i updated the code above.   This didn't work either.

Comment: Can anyone please help